# Storing this object in custom private variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, global

I have this js object

```
var toggleItem = {

  attrData : '',
  toggleNew : '',
  toggleOld : '',
  //var self : this,

  init : function(){

    self = this;
    self.listener();
  },

  listener : function(){

    jQuery('.btn-save').click(function(){
      var current = this.id.split('_').pop();
      self.toggleNew = jQuery('.toggle-data-new_'+current).val();
      self.toggleOld = jQuery('.toggle-data-old_'+current).val();
      self.updateForm();
    });
   },

  updateForm : function(){

    jQuery('#toggle-product-form #new').val(self.toggleNew);
    jQuery('#toggle-product-form #old').val(self.toggleOld);
    jQuery('#toggle-product-form').submit();
  },

 }
```

In the past i have often come across the issue of `this` value getting changed to whatever element I reference with `jQuery`. In this case I would like to store `this` in a new variable called `self`. But it is important that `self` does not become globally available.

You'll see at the top of the object where I wrote `//var self : this,` is now commented out. This is because placing `var` in front of it renders this error - `Unexpected identifier` in the console. But if I remove the `var` part I'm left with the same problem as I have now by placing it in the `init` function (it's global).

**Question** I want it to be available to everything inside the object and nothing outside?

Whatever solution works I would also plan to apply to the other three variables declared at the top.

**NB** I know I could use the name of the object instead of self and leave this global with relatively little risk of it conflicting with something else but I'm sure there has to be a way of re-assigning the value of `this` whilst keeping it only accessible (in its current form) from within the `toggleItem` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would follow along the lines of Mike's recommendation, but go the full Module pattern route. This will allow you to have "private" functions as well in the event that you want to collect any common functionality.

With this solution, I don't see a need for the `self` variable, unless you have something else you didn't share. The **encapsulation** provided here, keeps everything collected together inside the one function, and you don't have all of those other functions visible on your object (which is a step up from tossing everything into global scope, but you can take it this further step).

```
var toggleItem = (function () {
    var self = this,
        attrData,
        toggleNew,
        toggleOld,
        init,
        listener,
        updateForm;

    init = function () {
        // This will call the "listener" function without the need for
        // "self", however you can specify it if you want to.
        listener();
    };

    listener = function () {
        jQuery('.btn-save').click(function () {
            var current = this.id.split('_').pop();

            // Again, you shouldn't need "self", but add it 
            // if it will ease your mind.
            toggleNew = jQuery('.toggle-data-new_' + current).val();
            toggleOld = jQuery('.toggle-data-old_' + current).val();
            updateForm();
        });
    };

    updateForm = function () {
        jQuery('#toggle-product-form #new').val(self.toggleNew);
        jQuery('#toggle-product-form #old').val(self.toggleOld);
        jQuery('#toggle-product-form').submit();
    };

    return {
        init: init
        // Add the other functions if you need to access them from outside 
        // the script here, but from what you showed, you should be fine
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need the self reference in your `listener` function. Try doing this:

```
var toggleItem = {
  // all your other stuff...
  listener: function() {
    var self = this;
    jQuery('.btn-save').click(function(){
      var current = this.id.split('_').pop();
      self.toggleNew = jQuery('.toggle-data-new_'+current).val();
      self.toggleOld = jQuery('.toggle-data-old_'+current).val();
      self.updateForm();
    });
  }
};
```

**Edit**: Alternatively, you could change all references to `self` to `toggleItem` since that's really what you're trying to access. If you want to declare `self` once without placing it in the global scope then you could use a very of the Module pattern.

```
var toggleItem = (function() {
  var self = {
    // other stuff...
    listener: function() {
      jQuery('.btn-save').click(function(){
        var current = this.id.split('_').pop();
        self.toggleNew = jQuery('.toggle-data-new_'+current).val();
        self.toggleOld = jQuery('.toggle-data-old_'+current).val();
        self.updateForm();
      });
    }
  };
  return self;
})();
```

This creates an enclosed scope so `self` doesn't leak and it immediately invokes the function so `toggleItem` is assigned the return value of the function.

Comment: this is only a small part of the overall object. I'd really like to know how to declare `this` once but for the whole object to use

Answer (score 1):

In the future, to make member variables private, you can use a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). This will prevent the variable from leaking into the global scope.

```
function toggleItem() {
  var self = this,
  attrData = '',
  toggleNew = '',
  toggleOld = '';

  function init(){
    self.listener();
  }

  function listener(){
    jQuery('.btn-save').click(function(){
      var current = this.id.split('_').pop();
      self.toggleNew = jQuery('.toggle-data-new_'+current).val();
      self.toggleOld = jQuery('.toggle-data-old_'+current).val();
      self.updateForm();
    });
   }

  function updateForm(){
    jQuery('#toggle-product-form #new').val(self.toggleNew);
    jQuery('#toggle-product-form #old').val(self.toggleOld);
    jQuery('#toggle-product-form').submit();
  }

  return init;
 }

var toggle = toggleItem();
toggle.init();
```